# Script fails in Webstorm but not from terminal

Tags: node.js, terminal, phantomjs, webstorm

I have a nodejs script that uses phantomjs-node to scrape a webpage. It works fine when I run from a terminal window, but not when I run from inside Webstorm via a run configuration for a Node JS application.

What could be causing the error in Webstorm?

I've already tried running the script from the terminal after commenting out the contents of .bash_profile and it still works. I've also checked the contents of `process.env` in another sample script and saw that the values are completely different in Webstorm vs. terminal.

The script:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph) {
    return ph.createPage(function(page) {
        return page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
            console.log("opened google? ", status);
            return page.evaluate((function() {
                return document.title;
            }), function(result) {
                console.log('Page title is ' + result);
                return ph.exit();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Terminal output (works great!):

```
opened google?  success
Page title is Google
```

Webstorm console output (fails):

```
/usr/local/bin/node phantom.js
phantom stderr: execvp(): No such file or directory


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: If you are on Mac, check this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/51677.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Webstorm does set a PATH variable, but it's different to the PATH variable your app gets when run in the terminal. My solution, a hack:

1. Type `node` to get to the REPL
2. Run `process.env`
3. Copy the contents of the PATH value
4. Add an environment variable to Webstorm called PATH that uses this value. It will overwrite the default PATH variable that Webstorm gives your app.

Done!

Comment: This finally helped me with Rubymine having the same issue.

Comment: How are you adding the environmental variable to webstorm?

Comment: @pgreen2 go to the Run/Debug Configurations screen, select the Node JS config you are trying to fix, then on the right amongst the fields like 'Path to Node' and 'Node Parameters' you should see a field called 'Environment Variables'. Click the '...' button there to get you to a CRUD screen for environment variables for the config.

Comment: @Trindaz Ahh... Right in front of my face.  Thanks.

Comment: why is this necessary in the first place? it works fine when in the cmd line.. is there a solution where this extra step isnt necessary?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mac see http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1160. This document was originally written for RubyMine, but it is applicable for WebStorm too.