# running NodeJs script from WebStorm gives "spawn cmd.exe ENOENT" error

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Executing nodejs script as Build Configuration on WebStorm fails with the following error:

```
Warning: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Running the same script from terminal works fine. The failing part is running grunt task(shell command):

```
function buildInserter(cb) {
  var defer = Q.defer();
  grunt.tasks([ 'shell:release-inserter' ], { gruntfile: './gruntfile.js' }, function () {
    defer.resolve();
    if( typeof cb === 'function' ) {
      cb();
    }
  });

  return defer.promise;
}
```

I tried approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11184496/246719), but it didn't help.

Comment: Either cmd.exe or node binary is not in environments path I guess.

Comment: **C:\Windows\system32** was missing. Thank you. May I ask you to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cmd.exe` file is located under the `c:\windows\system32` folder.

The shortcut `%system32%` can be used within environment settings.

Add `c:\windows\system32` to your `PATH` environment variable and it should work!